# How to resize ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

after showing the ModalPopupExtender, there are two radio buttons that are displayed as part of the popup.  When you select the second radio button, I display more information in a gridview control.  When the ModalPopupExtender first displays, I have it set at 40% for width and height for the panel associated with the popup.  After clicking the second radio button, I would like to resize the popup to 80% for width and height.  My question is how do you resize ModalPopupExtender after it's initial popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript, something like this

```
d = document.getElementById('<%= PupupContainer.ClientID>');
d.style.width="80%";
```